# Number of Ways to reach N steps

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, fibonacci, counting

So I was doing this simple Dynamic Programming question about reaching the `n` th step while only being able to go 1 or 2 steps at a time. I know the answer is basically a **fibonacci** sequence and the answer is: # of steps to reach `n-2` + # of steps to reach `n-1`.

```
 T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2);
```

However, the more I think about it, the less sure of this I was. Should there not be an extra step at the end to reach the `n` th step itself? Obviously when I plug in numbers it works out, but I am wondering why there isn't an extra step at the end to signify actually reaching n instead of `n-1` and `n-2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are finding **Number of Ways** to reach N steps. Right? We are not finding **Number of moves**. (Let's say in each move you can make one or two steps.)

To reach `n` th spep the previous move can be reaching `n-1` th step or `n-2` th step. Thse are two different **ways** to reach `n`. Going from `n-1` to `n` or from `n-2` to `n` adds another **step**. But it is the same **way**.

Comment: AHHH right I overthought it and confused myself. Thanks that definitely helped!